# SSRS not working from remote locations

Tags: sql-server, security, reporting-services

I have couple of reports that I developed and are sitting on `http//localhost/reports`.

I have everything else set up, including Sql Server 2005 Config Tools. The reports run fine when I run them on my own machine, where IIS and Sql Server 2005 are both loaded. But they don't work when I try from other computers. I have the dir security to windows integrated security checked.

The error i get is -

> An error has occurred during report processing. Cannot create a
>   connection to data source 'time_clock'. Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

How do I make them available for remote users?

Answer (score 1):

Is the reportserver and SQL server on the same box? If SSRS is on a different box and MSSQL is on your box, then you have to configure Kerberos for double hop authentication.

Check this [link](http://mkdot.net/blogs/dejan/archive/2008/03/07/kerberos-solution-for-double-hop-authentication.aspx) for help on configuring double hop authentcation.

Raj

Comment: Dead link, but this one works: http://mkdot.net/mknetug/b/dejan/archive/2008/03/07/kerberos-solution-for-double-hop-authentication.aspx

Comment: Does this only apply if you are connecting to the report server database using windows auth, rather than stored credentials?

Answer (score 1):

SSRS machine authenticates the remote user, it impersonates him and it then tries to authenticate to the SQL machine. The SQL machine needs a proof that SSRS is who it claims it is (the remote user), but SSRS does not have the said proof (namely the password of the remote user), therefore authentication falls back to the anonymous logon.

To enable this scenario you need to [enable and configure constrained delegation](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/df979570-81f6-4586-83c6-676bb005b13e.mspx?mfr=true) on the account running the SSRS. If constrained delegation is enabled and properly configured then the domain controller will vouch for the SSRS machine impersonated identity of the remote user and the SQL machine will authenticate it successfully.

Comment: +1: Nice answer Remus. It's funny, Authentication and Permissions with Reporting Services seem to cause quite a few people issues. I suspect that SSRS 2008 will alleviate this somewhat by no longer being dependent on IIS.

Comment: ur answer looks like for win 2003, but i am running all this on my machine which has win xp professional SP3. How do i do it there?

Comment: @sinisana: same way, the important think is to download and use setspn.exe from MS site.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to turning Windows Authentication on, you need to turn Anonymous authentication off.

Comment: it is off.. i still get this problem

Comment: It's off in IIS? At the Application level?